# Stripe Django no such price

Tags: django

I have a problem with my Django Stripe Checkout. I tried to make checkout with pricing of items from my e-commerce website but i get an error from Stripe.
ERROR:

Request req_wfYpUxo6bE40lR: No such price: '2.00'

Models.py

```
class Item(Visits, models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', default='static/images/man.png')
    description = models.TextField(default="Item")
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            item = Item.objects.get(title='Kola')
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                line_items=[
                    {
                        # TODO: replace this with the `price` of the product you want to sell
                        'price': item.price,
                        'quantity': 1,
                    },
                ],
                payment_method_types=[
                'card',
                'p24',
                ],
                mode='payment',
                success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('success-page'))+ '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                cancel_url= request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('cancel-page')),
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(e)
    return redirect(checkout_session.url, {'item': item}, code=303)
```

Comment: Seems like the `Price` object does not exist in Stripe.

Comment: Emm What does it mean how can i solve it, do i have to make to each item Price on stripe website? What if i have a cart model?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe accepts amount in the currency's lowest amount format.

For example:

If you want to tell stripe that you want to deduct $1 from user, you need to represent $1 in form of cents i.e.

```
$1 = 100 cents (passing 100 to stripe as price)
```

**NOTE**: stripe doesn't accept any decimal format i.e. if you pass 100.00 if will throw an error, so before passing pass the converted amount to `int()` to eliminate that.